# document.location

Tags: javascript, html

How do you use document.location? Is it HTML or in JS? Please help me out!

Comment: Basically, I need a button, using document.location, with the URL hide://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**document** is a DOM element. to access it you can use **javascript** or **dom api**.

Answer (score 9):

It is javascript.

`document.location.href="http://www.google.com";` would redirect you go google

Comment: Can you give me some sample code with a button and a link to google?

Comment: Hey Would this work? <input type="button" value="Save Image" onclick="document.location.href="hide://;" />

Comment: Basically, I need a button, using document.location, with the URL hide://

Comment: @Henry - I think that should work.. but what do you mean `hide://`.. is that some special URL listener you have?

Comment: Yes it is. So <input type="button" value="Save Image" onclick="document.location.href="hide://;" /> will work?

Comment: Yes, it should I believe. Why not just try it out?

Comment: Whoops, my code was wrong. Its 
<input type="button" value="Save Image" onclick=document.location.href="hide://;"/>

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript location object is a property of the window object. It can be used to control the web page displayed by the browser.

More methods and property : http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javalocation.html

**reload() -** The current window document is reloaded. If a value of true is passed to the reload function, the reload is forced to do an HTTP GET of the document. This is not normally done but is useful when you think the server contents may be different from your cache.

`replace(URL) -` Requires a URL as a parameter. It loads the document at the URL on top of the current document. A new entry entry is not placed in the history object.