# list of page redirection techniques in HTML & javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.location="abc.html";
window.location.href = "abc.html";
window.location.assign("abc.html");
window.location.replace("abc.html");

<a href="abc.html">link</a>
```

I know these techniques in JS to redirect page to another 
but are there any other methods ? ? ?

help me with it .

Comment: Should you include tags in the title? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the **problem** you're facing. _"Are there any other methods?"_ is not a **problem**. Can you please elaborate on your question and explain the issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: question should be related to specific problem and not class homework list of page redirection techniques..

Comment: actully i need a diffrent way to redirect on another page after submitting  form   ...

Comment: And why do you need a different way?

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways too

From HTML page

[Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)

window.open()

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

document.location

[document.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901974/document-location)

Comment: @  jaydev thakkar Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work